# Why is the result of the code offered by Deep Learning with TensorFlow different from the snapshot in its book

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, mnist

In the first chapter of *Deep Learning with TensorFlow*, it gives an example on how to build a simple neural network for recognizing handwritten digits. According to its description, the code bundle for the book can be found at [GitHub](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Deep-Learning-with-TensorFlow-2-and-Keras).

From the context, I think section *Running a simple TensorFlow 2.0 net and establishing a baseline* uses the code same with [Deep-Learning-with-TensorFlow-2-and-Keras/mnist_V1.py](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Deep-Learning-with-TensorFlow-2-and-Keras/blob/master/Chapter%201/mnist_V1.py). When I run this example code, it gives me the following output:

[image]

The snapshot from the book is:

[image]

The result in my screenshot is `375/375` while in the snapshot of the book is `48000/48000`. Also, I miss the line `Train on 48000 samples, validate on 12000 samples`. Why this happens? How can I get the same result with the snapshot from the book?

From my output, I think the size of mine loaded datasets is the same with what it describes in the code:

[image]

```py
# loading MNIST dataset
# verify
# the split between train and test is 60,000, and 10,000 respectly 
# one-hot is automatically applied
mnist = keras.datasets.mnist
(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

My package versions:

```sh
$ python --version
Python 3.6.8
$ python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
2.3.1
$ python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.keras.__version__)'
2.4.0
```

---

I tried to find answer from the source code. The `fit` method is defined at [training.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2be88a7f1a42ca8ff623e6953d7439ec284f67b8/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L857). In this method, it instantiates a [CallbackList](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2be88a7f1a42ca8ff623e6953d7439ec284f67b8/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py#L204) object which then creates [ProgbarLogger](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2be88a7f1a42ca8ff623e6953d7439ec284f67b8/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py#L943).

```py
# training.py class Model method fit

      # Container that configures and calls `tf.keras.Callback`s.
      if not isinstance(callbacks, callbacks_module.CallbackList):
        callbacks = callbacks_module.CallbackList(
            callbacks,
            add_history=True,
            add_progbar=verbose != 0,
            model=self,
            verbose=verbose,
            epochs=epochs,
            steps=data_handler.inferred_steps)
```

```py
# callbacks.py class ProgbarLogger

  def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
    self._reset_progbar()
    if self.verbose and self.epochs > 1:
      print('Epoch %d/%d' % (epoch + 1, self.epochs))

  def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    self._batch_update_progbar(batch, logs)

  def _batch_update_progbar(self, batch, logs=None):
    # ...

    if self.verbose == 1:
      # Only block async when verbose = 1.
      logs = tf_utils.to_numpy_or_python_type(logs)
      self.progbar.update(self.seen, list(logs.items()), finalize=False)
```

`ProgbarLogger` then calls [ProgBar](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py#L493) update method to update the progress bar.

```py
# generic_utils.py class ProgBar method update

    if self.verbose == 1:
      # ...

      if self.target is not None:
        numdigits = int(np.log10(self.target)) + 1
        bar = ('%' + str(numdigits) + 'd/%d [') % (current, self.target)
```

`375` is the value of `self.target`. I then find out the value of `self.target` is passed from the `steps` parameter of `CallbackList` object. In the first code snippet, you can see `steps=data_handler.inferred_steps`. The property `inferred_steps` is defined at [data_adapter.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py#L1213).

```py
  @property
  def inferred_steps(self):
    """The inferred steps per epoch of the created `Dataset`.
    This will be `None` in the case where:
    (1) A `Dataset` of unknown cardinality was passed to the `DataHandler`, and
    (2) `steps_per_epoch` was not provided, and
    (3) The first epoch of iteration has not yet completed.
    Returns:
      The inferred steps per epoch of the created `Dataset`.
    """
    return self._inferred_steps
```

I got lost on how `self._inferred_steps` is calculated.

I think the miss line is related with [training_arrays_v1.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9489702e35b16a40a1accf3b8b5ed557efae10c7/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays_v1.py#L468). But I don't know what does V1 mean.

```py
def _print_train_info(num_samples_or_steps, val_samples_or_steps, is_dataset):
  increment = 'steps' if is_dataset else 'samples'
  msg = 'Train on {0} {increment}'.format(
      num_samples_or_steps, increment=increment)
  if val_samples_or_steps:
    msg += ', validate on {0} {increment}'.format(
        val_samples_or_steps, increment=increment)
  print(msg)
```

Comment: Just in case print yours `X_train.shape` and `Y_train.shape` prior to `model.fit()` call and let us know what you get please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question.

Let us break it into smaller parts.

You train on 48.000 samples and test on 12.000. However, your code display 375 instead of 48.000.

If you look at the batch size, its value is 128.

A quick division ---> `48.000 // 128 = 375`

Your code is correct, which is good.

The problem comes from the fact that, in older version of Keras and TensorFlow, the entire samples per step were shown (48.000), regardless of the batch_size used. In this example, the progress bar is updated like: `0, 128, 256 .... until 48.000`.

Now, in more recent versions, the `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` parameters are equal to the number of samples (say `48.000`) divided to the `batch_size` dimension (say `128`), hence the `375`.

Both displays are correct, it is just a matter of different progress bars, I personally agree and prefer the latter, since, if you have a batch_size of `128`, I would rather agree with the logic of seeing `1, 2, 3 ... 375`.

Update for further clarification:

Here you have a detailed description of the `model.fit()` arguments.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit

> steps_per_epoch   Integer or None. Total number of steps (batches of
> samples) before declaring one epoch finished and starting the next
> epoch.
>
> validation_steps  Only relevant if validation_data is provided and is
> a tf.data dataset. Total number of steps (batches of samples) to draw
> before stopping when performing validation at the end of every epoch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's reasonable. I tried to find code support with your saying 'the `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` parameters are equal to the number of samples (say 48.000) divided to the `batch_size` dimension (say 128)' but failed. I update my answer with where I'm stuck with. Could you please give me a favor?

Comment: Thank you very much, I think 'When training with input tensors such as TensorFlow data tensors, the default None is equal to the number of samples in your dataset divided by the batch size' in the documentation is the answer.

Comment: Yes, that is the answer. Also, since you marked the answer as accepted, could you also upvote it? It helps me and the others who run into this issue.

Comment: I actually ask two questions: 1) why 375 is different from 18000. 2) why the line `Train on 48000 samples, validate on 12000 samples` is missing. The upvote is for complete answers.

Comment: Well,  375 is not in essence different from 18000; it is a matter of logic, the backpropagation performs the same number of iterations. This is for the first question. The second one I do not know for sure, but I expected that you did not explicitly pass the steps per epoch and validation steps parameters. Also ensure that you pass the verbosity level to 1, to print every informative process

Comment: @With regard to "complete answers". I understand your point, but also please note that you have updated the question in the meantime while I answered your first question, now you extended with two more questions that I also answered. I gladly helped, but please note that multiple questions asked under a simple question is not recommended at all, since one could ask and ask and ask endlessly.

Comment: Also, regarding _V1, that you say you do not understand. Some methods from TensorFlow V1 version have been ported to TensorFlow V2, (>=2.0.0) so you are likely to see more of these in the codebase. Note that 18000 is not different from 375 effectively when training the model, only the printing logic is different.